# Python 3.5 os.execl not working as it should on Windows 10

Tags: windows, python-3.x, exec

I would like to restart my python script from within itself. So I wrote a small test script:

```
def restart_program():

    print ("Restarting")
    python = sys.executable
    os.execl(python, python, * sys.argv)

if __name__ == "__main__":

if answer.lower().strip() in "y yes".split():
    restart_program()
```

So, in theory, I suppose to get indefinite "Restarting" to be printed in the console. And it is exactly what happens - except with **Python 3.5** on **Windows 10**.

When switching to **Python 3.5** on **Windows 10** - it sucks. I need to press enter twice in order to get next "Restarting". And in more complicated script it crashes.

I also tried **MacOS** - It works fine on both **Python 2.7** and **Python 3.5**

Can someone suggest a correct way to do it on **Windows 10**?